# Can you set a NODE_ENV variable for a staging site url in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using the following NODE_ENV variable to use a different API depending on whether i'm in development mode or on the live site
 `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'`

I also have a staging site hosted which i would like to use the same API as the development (local) project. Is there a way to set a URL as another NODE_ENV variable? So that my staging URL can be accessed via for example process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'?

I would like  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' to be my local project and  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' to be my staging URL eg. https://www.stagingsite.com. How would this be set?

Comment: You just set it however you'd set any normal environment variable on your system, or you can use [`.env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: @tadman can you share any examples please? i have never done this for a particular project before

Comment: This depends entirely on your operating system and/or distribution's default method for doing it. I'd recommend `.env`, it's much harder to foul up.

Comment: The setup of my project is i have a local environment which uses a particular API link, then after i build the project, I upload it to a staging link which i want to be treated as "development" as well. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Every bootstrap provides their way to do this.
If you are using create-react-app then... try this
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used

then create env files after that place script commands and provide file location and name and run build script with appropriate env

```
"scripts": {
"build": "react-app-env --env-file=config/${BUILD_ENV}.env build",
"build:staging": "BUILD_ENV=staging npm run build",
"build:production": "BUILD_ENV=production npm run build",
...
}
```

try this for now although react-app-env is deprecated now .. this is code snippetfrom my old project... now cra and dotenv is enough .. although i need to create the flow

Comment: Thanks! this looks like what i need to do however i'm not entirely sure how to achieve what i want. The setup of my project is i have a local environment which uses a particular API link, then after i build the project, I upload it to a staging link which i want to be treated as "development" as well. What's the best way to achieve this?